# Algorithm to prove that an event occurred before a point of time

Tags: algorithm, sequence

Suppose we have an event and we want to prove that the event occurred after a particular date, we have a few easy ways of doing so. For example, one may just show a snapshot of a newspaper with a particular date and headline, indicating that the event is at least after that day. Or we could put in the ending stock price in a particular exchange of a particular date to say that it was after the end of trading hours of that day. This could be as fine grained to the second after the time when the exchange closed.

How to do the converse ? How can one say that an event occurred before a particular point of time ? One could depict large events (skyline of NYC to show various before or after WTC) and geological changes, but that is a very large-scale measure. Is there a much more fine-grained way to depict the fact, of the granularity of a few hours or days ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about programming or computing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash up the information you need to preserve (e.g. with a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) and publish the resulting hash value openly. This doesn't disclose any usable information, but if you later need to prove precedence, you can disclose the values you hashed up to show you had the information at that time.

I heard a story of AT&T paying for newspaper advertisements, long before computer security was mainstream, which disclosed a hash value. After a while the paper became worried that they were publishing mysterious advertisements every day that looked like secret codes and AT&T had to explain to the newspaper what the function of these were.

(A web search finds https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg13318103-800-technology-computer-fraudsters-foiled-by-the-small-ads/ including

Bellcore began running its advertisements in the New York Times in October
1991. They were interrupted for several months when newspaper employees
became suspicious of their cryptic contents. ‘Somebody said, ‘These look
like codes. You might be telling a terrorist to kill somebody,’ says Haber.
Fortunately for Bellcore, the Times’ computer correspondent persuaded the
newspaper to allow the advertisements back in.

Beware - article is buried in CSS and cookie notifications and inline ads)